# How to add span element inside td element while using .html(value To show) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My aim is to append data using `<span>` element inside of `<td>`. But I have to use `.html()` in jquery used inside loop.
Now I'm getting the result using this code as,

```
$("td", row).eq(2).html(dateval);
```

The result i'm getting is,

```
<td>XYZ</td>
```

But I needs, the result as,

```
<td><span>My calculated value</span>XYZ</td>
```

How to append this span element inside td using this .html method. Any suggestions welcomed!.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `html()`. Would an answer based on other jQuery methods not be acceptable?

Comment: What is content of `dateval`?

Comment: @trincot and Mohammad ,Thanks for your valuable time. I found a suitable solution below it just appended directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.html('<span>My calculated value</span>' + dateval);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by concatenating a `<span>My calculated value</span>` string with your value `dateval`.

```
var calcVal = '<span>My calculated value</span>'+ dateval;
$("td", row).eq(2).html(calcVal);
```